# How do I list ids via MDX?

Tags: vba

The question is, how can i retrieve the info in the way below?

```
LETTER | ID | NAME
  A    | 01 | xxxx
  A    | 02 | xxyy
  A    | 03 | xyz
  B    | 04 | aaaa
  B    | 05 | aabb
  C    | 06 | yyy
...
```

***Quick edit here:***

I tried to run this query

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[ID] AS [Item ID].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT
   [Measures].[ID] ON COLUMNS,
   [Letter].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

And the result was

```
LETTER | ID
   A   | All
   B   | All
   C   | All
   D   | All
   E   | All
```

Just to give some context here, I intend to get this unique ID and retrieve all the info related to it and then write on a Excel row, for example, all of that using VBA.

***New edit!***

It worked very well, but I tried to make some mods, without success.
As I said, I'm pretty new to OLAP cube, but I do have a background in SQL.

Maybe the real question is:

What is the best practice to do that? Should I try to transform OLAP Cube into a flat file? How can manage this data before printing it?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve information from a spreadsheet?

Comment: No! Actually I'm retrieving from a cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe more like this:

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[ID] AS 
    [Item ID].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY
SELECT
   [Measures].[ID] ON 0,
    [Letter].ALLMEMBERS 
   *[Item ID].[Item ID].MEMBERS
   ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```